# Disable ListViewItem reveal effect of UWP ListView control

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Windows UWP recently introduced the [reveal effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal) for some controls. I would like to turn them off, especially for the `ListView` control. How can I do that?

I've already tried setting the ListView Resources without any luck:

```xml
<ListView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackground" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Red" />
</ListView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can set it by using the `DefaultListViewItemStyle` style inside the `ListViewItem`. I did not manage to set it via `ItemContainerStyle` and a `Setter`, but it works if you directly add the `ListViewItem` inside the `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyViewModel">
        <ListViewItem Style="{ThemeResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">
            <Grid><!--Content--></Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```